# get specific values from rails array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby-on-rails-3, loops

I think I have a correct array going for rails?

```
@lv = {'apple' => ['tags', 'red'], 'name' => ['more tags', 'taggers']}
```

I was wondering how I can display certain parts through a loop. For instance, how would I only display `apple` and `name`?

```
<% @lv.each do |me| %>
   <%= me %>
<% end %>
```

This just displays the whole @lv message, and doesn't only display `apple` and `name`. And then I'd like to be able to get only the tagged values of specific ones, so say if I need to get tagged value of `apple`, it should only display `tags` and `red` How do I do this with rails?

Thanks!

Comment: In regards to the second part of your question, what does "the tagged values of specific ones" mean? Is the `tags` item in the array special in some way?

Comment: @Teeg I want to be able to output each tag, if I its something like key[0] or something? Not sure how it is, but if its something like PHP, I'd call the first array and then it'll output the values from the first array key which is apple (using a loop with key[0] or something), does that make more sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `@lv` variable is a hash, so using `.each` will only give you a combined key-value pair as the block parameter (that's what `me` ends up being). Instead, use `each_pair`; that way you can get separated variables for the keys and the values. Like so:

```
<% @lv.each_pair do |key, value| %>
    <%= key %>
<% end %>
```

**Edit**

This is in response to your comment in the question as well. The `key` will end up being just the `apple`, or `name`, part of your hash. The `value` parameter is whatever is pointed to by the key, which in this case is the actual array of items (which I think is what you're calling tags). For example, your hash contains two key-value pairs, and as we iterate over them, in the first loop `key` = `apple`, and `value`=`['tags', 'red']`. To output that array of values, you could do it a couple of different ways:

Loop over the tag array

```
<% @lv.each_pair do |key, value| %>
    <%= key %>
    <%= value.each do |tag| %>
        <%= tag %>
    <%= end %>
<% end %>
```

As a comma separated string:

```
....looping code
    <%= value.join(", ") %>
```

Or just spit it out as-is in array notation:

```
....looping code
    <%= value %>
```

Or if you just wanted a specific element in the value array, then yes you can just do `value[0]`, or `value[1]`...etc.

Let me know whether that is not what you are asking.

Comment: I want to be able to output the key in some kind of link. So if user clicks on `apple`, the tags should show up. In other words, how do I just output the tags that are specific to the names only (`apple` or `name`)?

Comment: This is exactly what I'm asking! Thank you very much!

Comment: There's one question: what if I just want to iterate through `apple` instead of `name`? Can I just do `@lv[0].each_pair`? or would the `[0]` be here: `@lv.each_pair do |key[0], value|`?

Comment: @andrewliu No you would reference the specific key by name, so you'd do `@lv[:apple].each do |apple_values| .....`

Comment: Hmm interesting, I have a question in related to this, what if the key is two words? how do you do something like `apple cin`? `@lv[:apple din]` won't work tho?

Comment: @andrewliu You cannot, no. They key is a single word. If you have a deeper structure like `{:apple=>{:more_apples=>"some value"}}` then you'd reference it like `@lv[:apple][:more_apples]`.